# Why isn't Proxy flag [P] working with my RewriteMap in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, centos7, digital-ocean, mod-proxy

I'm trying to get this RewriteRule working, but the Proxy flag [P] is behaving like a redirect:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAPTO:${domainmap:%1}]
RewriteCond %{ENV:MAPTO} !=""
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://mywebsite.com/%{ENV:MAPTO}/$0/ [P,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I enabled rewrite logging by using `LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6`, which confirmed that a match is being found in my map, but from my log:

```
RewriteCond: input='proxiedwebsite.com' pattern='^(?:www\\.)?(.+)$' [NC] => matched
map lookup OK: map=domainmap key=proxiedwebsite.com -> val=path/to/dynamic-content
setting env variable 'MAPTO' to 'path/to/dynamic-content'
strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/mywebsite.com/html/ -> 
applying pattern '^.*$' to uri ''
RewriteCond: input='path/to/dynamic-content' pattern='!=""' => matched
rewrite '' -> 'https://mywebsite.com/path/to/dynamic-content/'
escaped URI in per-dir context for proxy, https://mywebsite.com/path/to/dynamic-content/ -> https://mywebsite.com/path/to/dynamic-content/
forcing proxy-throughput with https://mywebsite.com/path/to/dynamic-content/
go-ahead with proxy request proxy:https://mywebsite.com/path/to/dynamic-content/ [OK]
```

What ends up happening is I get `https://mywebsite.com/path/to/dynamic-content/` in my address bar instead of the intended `https://proxiedwebsite.com`.

And here's what my Apache config looks like:

```
<Directory "/var/www/mywebsite.com/html">
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias mywebsite.com proxiedwebsite.com www.proxiedwebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com/html
    UseCanonicalName Off
    ProxyRequests On
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/cert/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cert/privkey.pem
    LogLevel alert rewrite:trace6
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also tried doing this without https on port 80, but I get the same issue.

**UPDATE**

I added `ProxyPreserveHost On` to my VirtualHost configuration and it seems to be responding to my rewrite conditions — however, it's creating a loop. After several seconds I'm getting a 403 Forbidden error with the `%{ENV:MAPTO}` variable repeated over and over again. Not sure why.

**UPDATE 2**

Okay, now I understand why `ProxyPreserveHost On` is creating a loop. But I still don't understand why my Proxy `[P]` flag is resulting in a 301 Redirect. So, back to the original problem.

Comment: Since main and proxied websites both share the same document root folder, why would you want to use `mod_proxy`? You could directly use internal rewrites, which would also be faster. Anyway, if you still want to go that way, I'd try adding a condition to check that the http host is not the proxied one. I suspect it creates a loop because the same code is executed for all your domains.

Comment: Content is dynamically generated based on path provided by the RewriteMap, but you're right about the shared document root folder. This seems to be a factor. I'm toying with assigning all proxied vhosts to a different root.